# Overwrite the return value of a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Usually a Stored Procedure return 0 on success execution without errors, and -1 or etc when the stored procedure encounter errors.
Is there anyway I can overwrite the int return value in the Stored Procedure?

Comment: Use function instead of storedprocedure.

Comment: You might [RETURN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) an int from procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [function description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) that will give you any return what you want.

Or if you need write access, you can add output parameters in you storedprocedure
Something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyStoredProcedure (
    @myInput NVARCHAR(50),
    @myOutput INT OUTPUT )
AS
SELECT @myOutput = COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn = @myInput
```

Comment: That's a function, not a stored procedure.

Comment: It returns even multiple values :) nice ...was gonna post the same.

Answer (score 0):

SP can return what ever you want to return by using select statement but ideally you should use functions when you need to return a single value.

Answer to your problem is yes!!

Comment: The `select` statement doesn't change the return value. Eventhough "yes" is a correct answer to the question, it's not useful. Naturally the question implies also "If so, then how?".

Comment: @Guffa what i meant was Select 1 and Select 'a'

Comment: Whatever you select, it will not change the return value. That is separate from the result/results that are returned from the procedure. A procedure may return zero or more results, but it always have a single integer return value.

Answer (score 0):

use the [`return` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx):

```
return 42
```